# c# linq sql coalesce conversion

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I'm trying to convert an existing sql stored proc to use linq. The stored proc uses coalesce() while building up the 'where' clause.

Below is what I've tried.

Can some give advice / other on the correct way to approach this conversion?

------- sql

```
    if @a is not null 
        set @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' and v.a_number = ''' + @a + ''''


    if @b is not null 
        set @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' and v.b_number = ''' + @b + ''''


    if @aDateMin is not null 
        set @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' and coalesce(v.a_end_dt, v.a_start_dt, ''1/1/1753'') 
            >= ''' + convert(varchar(10), @aDateMin, 101) + ''''


    if @aDateMax is not null 
        set @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' and coalesce(v.a_start_dt, v.a_end_dt, ''12/31/9999'') 
            <= ''' + convert(varchar(10), @aDateMax, 101) + ''''

set @Sql =      from Results v
                @WhereClause ;';

--print @Sql
exec sp_executesql @Sql
```

-----linq

```
var aNumber = "";
var bNumber = "";
DateTime? aDateMin = null;
DateTime? aDateMax = null;

var query =     from v in searchResults
                select v;

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(aNumber )){
    query = query.Where(v => v.a_number == aNumber);
}

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bNumber)){
    query = query.Where(v => v.b_number == bNumber);
}


//  this is where I'm having issue with the conversion.
if(aDateMin.HasValue){

    query = query.Where(v => 
                        v.a_end_dt.HasValue ? v.a_end_dt >= aDateMin : v.a_start_dt.HasValue ? v.a_start_dt <= aDateMin : "1/1/1753");

}
```

Comment: That "dynamic" sql gives me the fear.

Comment: It's not clear how `aDateMin` might be non-null.

Comment: That's why I'm needing to convert it. the aDateMin value will come from search field in UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried it, but could you try something like:

```
var dt = new DateTime(1753, 1,1);
query = query.Where(v =>  (v.a_end_dt ?? v.a_start_dt ?? dt) >= aDateMin);
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, using the `??` (c# equivalent of `COALESCE`) might do the trick :

```
if(aDateMin.HasValue){
    query = query.Where(v => 
                        aDateMin.Value < v.a_end_dt ?? v.a_start_dt ?? new DateTime(1753, 1, 1));
```

Or another formulation :

```
query = query.Where(v => 
                        aDateMin.HasValue.Value < v.a_end_dt ?? v.a_start_dt ?? new DateTime(1753, 1, 1));
```